# Can't install poski successfully at linux

Tags: linux

I want to install poski at linux(both centos 5.3 and ubuntu 11.10). I do the command below:

```
../poski-v1.0.0/INSTALL.sh --with-oski=yes --prefix=/usr/local/poski
```

The error is below, the same for centos and ubuntu.

```
../../poski-v1.0.0/include/poski/poski_commontype.h:4: fatal error: oski/oski.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: seems like you have a missing header `oski.h`. Try downloading again the package.

Comment: the same error after I reload a package again.I checked the oski.h is at /home/taoyuan/project/poski/poski-v1.0.0/oski/oski-1.0.1h/include/oski/oski.h. and my working directory is /home/taoyuan/project/poski/build-1.0.0